# Can a javascript async method return multiple values at different times?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list of values that I wanna return asynchronously, but a limited number of values at a time.

So I call my function once and it has an array of say 20 distinct elements say [1,2,...,20], and it keeps on returning 5 elements every second. So I want:
[1,2,..,5] at 0 sec,
[6,7,..,10] at 1 sec,
and so on....

I was thinking on using buffer files. If it is a valid solution, can someone tell me how to implement it for the given example?

Comment: You are having a case of [XY problem](http://www.xyproblem.info). Meaning that you should instead ask what is it you are dealing with, instead of asking whether an async function can "return multiple values at different times" which is most definitely the wrong question here.

Comment: @amn, Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely keep that in mind the next time I ask questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An async *generator* function (or method) can yield (loosely, return) a sequence of values over time. Here's an example:

```js
function sleepRandom(maxMs) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * maxMs)));
}

async function *example(max) {
    yield -1; // Example of explicit value
    
    // Wait 500ms
    await sleepRandom(800);

    // Example of loop
    for (let i = 0; i < max; ++i) {
        // Wait 500ms
        await sleepRandom(800);

        // Yield current loop value
        yield i;
    }
    
    // All done
    yield "Done";
}

(async () => {
    for await (let value of example(10)) {
        console.log(value);
    }
})()
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

The `*` after `function` is what makes it a generator function. The `async` before `function` is what makes it `async`.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could use nodes [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) for that:

```js
var events = require('events');

function spitChunks(arr, chunksize = 5, delay = 1000, em = null) {
    if(!em) em = new events.EventEmitter();
    if(arr.length > 0) setTimeout(() => {
        em.emit('nextChunk', arr.splice(0,chunksize));
        spitChunks(arr, chunksize, delay, em);
    }, delay);
    return em;
}

let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
let emitter = spitChunks(numbers);

emitter.on('nextChunk', data => console.log(data));
```